# How do I make Subversion use a third-party diff tool?

Tags: linux, svn, diff, beyondcompare

I need more than the default diff! I have recently purchased "Beyond Compare" and I'd like to integrate it with svn, so its launched when I type:

svn diff foo.c

How do I do this?

Comment: The original question mentioned Linux. That should probably have been left in the title of the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From a [Beyond Compare forum post](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=41520):

/usr/bin/bcompare_svn:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bcompare $6 $7 &
exit 0
```

The invocation of bcompare is obvious but I had to add "exit 0" so that svn would open more than one file at a time.

To make svn invoke my script, I added the following line in the [helpers] section in ~/.subversion/config

```
diff-cmd=/usr/bin/bcompare_svn
```

Answer (score 12):

Look at svn --diff-cmd.

Comment: with --diff-cmd  svn client (mine is 1.6.6) still generates -L options to the specified command, as in -L "file1 (rev xyz)" -L "file2 (rev abc)" So, unless your diff cmd is OK with those, it's broken. Chris has a good workaround in his Beyond Compare page, which involves creating a launcher script.

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to add a comment to Andy Lester's answer but I don't have a big enough reputation. However, I can answer the question, I guess.

Anyways... as Andy already noted run "svn help diff" but to just give you the answer...

svn diff --diff-cmd <diff-cmd> --extensions <diff-cmd options>

svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff --extensions "-bca" <filename(s)>

Answer (score 4):

I recently added instructions for Subversion on Linux to our [Using Beyond Compare With Version Control Systems](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs.php) web page. Once you follow the steps at the above link it should launch Beyond Compare 3 for Linux when you run "svn diff".

Answer (score 4):

In latest Subversion, the script /usr/bin/bcompare_svn should be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp $6 $6.save
cp $7 $7.save
{
    /usr/bin/bcompare $6.save $7.save 
    rm $6.save $7.save
} &
exit 0
```

or (untested code)

```
#!/bin/bash
base=`echo $3 | sed -r "s/^([^\(]+)[ \t]+\((.+)\)$/\1.\2/g" | xargs -i% basename "%"`
current=`echo $5 | sed -r "s/^([^\(]+)[ \t]\((.+)\)$/\1.\2/g" | xargs -i% basename "%"`

mv "$6" "/tmp/$base"
mv "$7" "/tmp/$current"
{
    /usr/local/bcompare/bin/bcompare "/tmp/$base" "/tmp/$current"
    rm "/tmp/$base" "/tmp/$current"
} &
exit 0
```

Comment: Why should it be done like that?  Any explanation for why you recommend this different script to the accepted answer, please?